# I am using AWS Cognito Service i am trying to remove OTP while Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am trying to design angular login page for authentication we are using cognito service
I want to remove OTP while Login how can i implement in cognito ?

Comment: Just disable MFA?

Comment: how to disable MFA in cognito?

Comment: Login to AWS console and open your cognito settings. It's not difficult to find

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have a presignup trigger?**  If not that's your first step.

In node, you would respond to the presignup event by modifying the incoming event like so:

```
event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
```

This bypasses the confirmation code flow, and immediately calls your post-confirmation trigger if you have one.

This specific use case is talked about here: [AWS Presignup Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example-2)

Comment: is this for sign in process?

Comment: I want user to verify through email only and if we add this in presignup trigger it will automatically verified

Comment: Oh ok.  Then thats a setting on the pool in the MFA section.  You might have to rebuild the pool, a lot of the setting cannot be changed after initial pool creation

Comment: Check this AWS doc.  https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-authentication-example